# Twitter Bootstrap2 three segment row where second spans remaining height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm trying to get a row cut into three segments following the below premises:

- First segment must have a max-height and always stay on top (min-height:0; max-height:40%). Minimum height can be 0. Scroll must appear if content doesn't fit max-height.
- Third segment must be placed on bottom (no fixed height). Height must be inherited from its content.
- Second segment must expand 100% of the remaining height. Scroll must appear if content doesn't fit remaining height.

I've tried with the following code https://gist.github.com/anonymous/24809e7b981f4ca7e6fb but the problem i'm experiencing is the middle/second segment expands to bottom overlapping the third segment.

Does anyone know how should i proceed? Thx

Comment: I think what you are doing should be placed in 3 rows instead of putting inside one row

Comment: They're already three different rows

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="first-row" style="max-height:40%;scroll:auto;"></div>
    <div class="second-row" style="height:100%;"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="third-row" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Tomás. Right now your solution is not working i updated the gist https://gist.github.com/anonymous/24809e7b981f4ca7e6fb The problem of your solution is second-row always spans to 100%+40% of the first-row so it overlaps third-row

Comment: @user846226 the inner rows should not have the row-fluid class i think. Like in my example (you might want to use row-fluid instead of row, but its the same)